# Multiplication of quadratic residues

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratic-residues

I know that the following is right, where QR is a qiadratic residue and NQR is not a quadratic residue.

QR*QR=QR

NQR*NQR=QR

And why must a QR ratio consist of a QR numerator and QR denomerator or both have to be NQR.

Comment: $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a quadratic residue or not just according to the value of $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$, and $$a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\cdot b^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=(ab)^{\frac{p-1}{2}},$$ i.e. the Legendre symbol is multiplicative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to understand this is through group theory.  The squaring map
\begin{align*}
\varphi: \mathbb{F}_p^\times &\to \mathbb{F}_p^\times\\
x &\mapsto x^2
\end{align*}
is a group homomorphism.  Since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field, then
$$
x^2 = 1 \iff 0 = x^2 - 1 = (x-1)(x+1) \iff x = \pm 1
$$
so $\ker(\varphi) = \{\pm 1\}$.  This shows that the subgroup of squares $\operatorname{img}(\varphi)$ has index $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$, so
$$
\mathbb{F}_p^\times/\operatorname{img}(\varphi) = \{\operatorname{QR}, \operatorname{NQR}\} \cong C_2 = \{\pm 1\}
$$
where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$ (written multiplicatively).  (As Jack D'Aurizio notes, we can also consider this as the map $\mathbb{F}_p^\times \to C_2$, $x \mapsto x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$.)  In this isomorphism, we have
\begin{align*}
\text{QR} &\leftrightarrow 1\\
\text{NQR} &\leftrightarrow -1 \, .
\end{align*}
Since this group has order $2$, by Lagrange's Theorem we have
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{QR} \cdot \operatorname{QR} &= \operatorname{QR}^2 = \operatorname{QR}\\
\operatorname{NQR} \cdot \operatorname{NQR} &= \operatorname{NQR}^2 = \operatorname{QR} \, .
\end{align*}

As an analogy, recall a more familiar example of a group with an index $2$ subgroup: the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and the subgroup $2 \mathbb{Z}$ of even integers.  We have similar rules for even and odd numbers, just with $\cdot$ replaced by $+$:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{even} + \operatorname{even} &= \operatorname{even}\\
\operatorname{odd} + \operatorname{odd} &= \operatorname{even}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer! But wha counts the same for ratios? So, a ratio is QR if and only if both parts are QR or NR, is it because of the multiplicity of the group?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of a QR is a QR, the multiplicative inverse of a NQR is a NQR.  Dividing is just multiplying by the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

your tags say abstract algebra. The quadratic residues are a subgroup of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z.$ The nonresidues are  the only other coset.